# What is error in this fortran program?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I am writing following fortran 90 program and compiling with GNU Fortran Compiler. However, I am getting some errors that I can't resolve. Can someone explain me where I am going wrong?

```
PROGRAM FILE1
IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER:: status,a,b,c,i,j

a=5
b=6
c=1

REAL,ALLOCATABLE,DIMENSION (:,:) :: arr1

ALLOCATE (arr1(a,b))

DO i=1,a,1
    DO j=1,b,1
        arr1(i,j)=c
        c=c+1
    END DO
END DO

DO i=1,a,1
    DO j=1,b,1
        WRITE (*,100,ADVANCE=NO) arr1(i,j)
        100 FORMAT (1X,I4.1)
    END DO
        WRITE (*,110)
        110 FORMAT ('',/)
END DO

DEALLOCATE(arr1)

END PROGRAM
```

I got several errors, e.g. in statement `REAL,ALLOCATABLE,DIMENSION (:,:) :: arr1` `Error: Unexpected data declaration statement at (1)`. I checked syntax from several sources, but no luck. There is error in statement `WRITE (*,100,ADVANCE=NO) arr1(i,j)` too. Can someone comment?

Comment: put the arr1 declaration on the line after the INTEGER:: declaration

Comment: Also, for `Advance = No`, the `No` should be in quotes as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The posted code has a couple of issues:

1. you need to define all your variables before you execute any other statement.

   ```
   a=5
   b=6
   c=1
   ```

should come after your last variable definition:

```
REAL,ALLOCATABLE,DIMENSION (:,:) :: arr1
```

2. You need to quote `NO` in the `WRITE` statement:

   ```
   WRITE (*,100,ADVANCE="NO") arr1(i,j)
   ```
3. Since you are writing a `REAL` value, you need to give a floating point format in such as `f` or `g`

   ```
   100 FORMAT (1X,f7.3)
   ```

The working code would be:

```
PROGRAM FILE1
IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER:: status,a,b,c,i,j

REAL,ALLOCATABLE,DIMENSION (:,:) :: arr1

a=5
b=6
c=1

ALLOCATE (arr1(a,b))

DO i=1,a,1
    DO j=1,b,1
        arr1(i,j)=c
        c=c+1
    END DO
END DO

DO i=1,a,1
    DO j=1,b,1
        WRITE (*,100,ADVANCE="NO") arr1(i,j)
        100 FORMAT (1X,f7.3)
    END DO
        WRITE (*,110)
        110 FORMAT ('',/)
END DO

DEALLOCATE(arr1)

END PROGRAM
```

Comment: Good answer. BTW, the code tags in the editor are just for Javascript. For other code just indent by 4 spaces to format it as code (you can do this by selecting code and pressing Ctrl-K).